# Accessing Google Sheets / Documents Blame API

Tags: google-api, google-sheets-api

We have a pretty deep integration with Google Sheets API going where I work, and last year they added an option to "blame" or pull the cell history from a given cell.

It pulls up a URL like: `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/0/d/$docId/blame?token=$tokenId&includes_info_params=true` for each request and that returns a little json document with the blame information.

I have not been able to find how to generate a token ID myself - which I think identifies the specific cell I have clicked.

Has anyone integrated with the blame API?  I cant find any docs for it in the API search pages.

Comment: Hi, could please tell me the github link of the Blame API library you want to implement?

Comment: That is kind of the issue - I cannot find it.  There is a feature on their public site that is "new" but has been there for 6 months.  It has a public URL I could call to get the data I need, but there doesn't seem to be public documentation for it yet.  I was hoping that someone with more Google API experience might be able to pinpoint where tokenId comes form (as I have the docId already).  It seems to be an identifier either for the request or for the cell.  It was a long shot, but I thought Ild ask.

Comment: Can you please send me the link/site where you found the public URL you're talking about? I don't seet it in Sheets API https://developers.google.com/sheets/api

Comment: I am asking for the same information you are I believe.  
The url above (as found in the console) returns the info I want.  It doesnt seem documented or part of a public api yet. If it is, I would want to use it and would hope someone could point it out.  If its not and an expert with the google API knew what tokenId meant, they might be able to help me use the endpoint I pointed out.

Comment: I also noticed this because I need to access edit history of specific cells. Google Sheets keeps crashing saying "request timed out" if I try to access edit history that happened to be a long time ago. Also, Google Sheets currently does not support public API to access edit history of each cell, despite being a fairly reasonable and general use case.